# Any possible fix for the alertmanager generatorURL breaking due to url-encoding issues

Tags: telegram, prometheus-alertmanager

I have set-up `alertmanager` and configured it using the [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/).
The set-up is made to send alerts to Slack, Email and Telegram via the alertmanager.
I have triggered some alerts to see if it is working fine. For Slack and Emails, the `generatorURL` (A backlink which identifies the causing entity of the alert.[1](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/)) is clickable and when clicked takes back to the `Grafana Explore` section which is the expected behaviour. However for Telegram, the `generatorURL` link is broken (The link is half clickable). The `alertmanager` uses [default template](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/a6d10bd5bc3f651e0ca04d47b981ed66e85a09a6/template/default.tmpl#:%7E:text=%7B%7B%20define%20%22__text_alert_list%22%20%7D%7D%7B%7B%20range,%7B%7B%20end%20%7D%7D%7B%7B%20end%20%7D%7D) to send the alerts to Telegram.

---

After some research, I found out that it is because of the url-encoding (i.e. The quotes, square brackets, etc. are not encoded). I don't know how to encode it manually. However I have tried two possible solutions:

1. Used `parseMode` as `HTML` and using anchor tag for the `generatorURL` - Didn't work.
2. Used `reReplaceAll` to replace the quotes, square brackets, etc. into url encoded form from this [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/42316) - Didn't work.

I tried the solution provided here, but I didn't get the source URL i.e. It was blank.

**What did I achieve:** It didn't generate the URL. I mean the telegram message was blank.

**What was expected:** A fully clickable source URL.

Screenshots have been attached.
[Implemented GitHub solution for GeneratorURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA09g.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS2bW.png)

Any suggestions on what can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try it in the same way as this ticket: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/2997 ? If you fall in a corner case, `{{ .GeneratorURL | reReplaceAll ...}}` should yield a workable solution. Please add some example, what you achieved while trying and what you expect.

Comment: Hello @MichaelDoubez
Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried the solution you mentioned above. I have also edited the message to include what was achieved and what was expected.